# access iphone settings

Tags: iphone, settings

I have saved an musicfile in the iphone path called-"/var/mobile/Applications/92B12BF1-88E1-4FD5-93DC-8311EC3B072A/Music" programmatically .Can I see those files in the iphone ?.Please tell me ,thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set in your Info.plist the itunes file sharing property, which will make *all* files in your app's Documents directory visible to users, both to copy to the desktop and to save files from the desktop to the phone:  "Application supports itunes file sharing" and check the box.

[image]

Comment: Still won't let other apps access it, though.

Comment: Well, it is a correct answer to  my interpretation of the somewhat ambiguous "Can I see those files in the iphone?"

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you jailbreak the phone. Other options are

1) store your file under `<Application_Home>/Documents`, then you can fetch the file from iTunes. You need to set `UIFileSharingEnabled` key in your `Info.plist` to YES.

2) run your program in your iOS simulator and examine the file.

Answer (score 0):

**`92B12BF1-88E1-4FD5-93DC-8311EC3B072A`** is a GUID, which means it will change.

Second, the only way for you to "view" files outside of your [applications sandbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_%28computer_security%29) is to be jailbroken.